# How to differentiate between a list and parallelism

Tags: grammar

In the phrase "inhibition of reflexes and skeletal relaxation", what sort of punctuation is used to differentiate between the 2 possible meanings - "inhibition of both **reflexes** and **skeletal relaxation**" and "**inhibition of reflexes** and **skeletal relaxation**"?

Comment: The way to resolve the ambiguity is not with punctuation (which can't do the job in this case) but with additional or altered wording. If you mean (1) inhibition of reflexes and (2) inhibition of skeletal relaxation, you can achieve clarity by saying either "inhibition of both reflexes and skeletal relaxation" or "inhibition of reflexes and of skeletal relaxation." If you mean (1) inhibition of reflexes and (2) skeletal relaxation, you can achieve clarity by rewording the first phrase to to avoid the "of" element: "reflex inhibition and skeletal relaxation."

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a list of only two items, it is better to rephrase the sentence (as already done in the case of one meaning in the question) than to rely solely on punctuation.

---

Without more extensive rewording, a common way of distinguishing the two is to use numbers in parentheses:

1. I want to discuss the inhibition of (1) reflexes and (2) skeletal relaxation.
2. I want to discuss (1) the inhibition of reflexes and (2) skeletal relaxation.

But if you are speaking *strictly* of punctuation, only *one* of the meanings can be made explicit—and it uses a nonstandard construction:

2. I want to discuss the inhibition of reflexes; and skeletal relaxation.

This use of a semicolon is awkward, because it would not normally be used in this fashion. On the other hand, it makes the meaning very clear. Sometimes, otherwise awkward punctuation is necessary to make meaning clear—and conveying meaning is, ultimately, more important than how it's conveyed. But only if there is no other way of doing so.

Note that a comma could also be used, but using a comma for only *two* list items is even more unusual in this context than a semicolon.

If the list contained three or more items, then (depending on the nature of the items) a combination of a colon, commas, and semicolons would be the normal way of punctuating it to avoid ambiguity.

---

Note that the sentence as written can also be interpreted a third way that has not yet been mentioned:

3. I want to discuss **the inhibition of reflexes and skeletal relaxation**.

In this interpretation, there is only a *single* thing being discussed.